# Flask route request hitting 2 routes at a time

Tags: python, flask

We have two routes set up on a webserver.

```
Route 1
@app.route('/<string:project>', defaults={'serialNumber':0})
@app.route('/<string:project>/<int:serialNumber>')
```

The first route is allows us to redirect to projects and serial numbers as required.

We also have an API on

```
Route 2 
@app.route('/api/<string:project>', methods=['GET'])
```

Both these routes do work as expected but when you hit the API route you also appear to hit route 1 (which errors out in the console on a line in route 1)

Is there anyway of telling flask to specifically ignore a route if string:project is "api" on route 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't actually hit the 2 routes. Routing starts looking for routes in the order it encounters them in your code. When routing finds a matching route, it stops looking.
2. From your code, when you type `/api/test_project`, it will match on `Route 1` if that comes first because your code says to match on a `string` ('api' meets this) followed by a number and 'test_project' fails this so you get the error
3. Since you want to specifically match on anything that starts with `api`, you should put that route first i.e. your Route 2 should become Route 1. This means you should have the following

```
# If the route start with /api/, then handle it
@app.route('/api/<string:project>', methods=['GET'])
    # Do something for the API route


# For any other routing (apart from /api/), handle it
@app.route('/<string:project>', defaults={'serialNumber':0})
@app.route('/<string:project>/<int:serialNumber>')
    # Do something for any other routing that does not start with /api/
```

Comment: Perfectly explained!